# Share NIC from 32-bit VM?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

My onboard NIC just failed after a lightning-related power outage and the only replacement NIC I have does not have 64-bit windows drivers.

Could I run a 32-bit windows VM, connect to my USB NIC then share that internet connection with the host machine?

Are there other alternatives? The offending 32-bit-only network adapter is a Sohoware NUB110 - 10/100 USB Adapter and the failed internal interface is just in a constant state of 'network cable unplugged'

I've already tried the standard troubleshooting for the failed NIC hence my focus on the VM alternative but here are the steps I've already tried for reference:
* Tested cable by plugging it into laptop and verifying it worked
* Disabled NIC in BIOS then rebooted and re-enabled
* shut down pc, unplugged power cable and Ethernet cable, pressed power button to discharge caps, removed BIOS settings battery, then restored all settings